# create form in spring using Drag and Drop?

Tags: java, spring

My task is,"Appication Managment"

Create Form using UI and save into Database

Create web Form using Drag-n -drop and save Into dataBase in java?

is it possible? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/). It has a very rich set of UI components with drag-drop feature.
I have used it once to create a dynamic form.